# R: Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, x, y) : Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf, self-intersection

I am new to using CRS on R and thus am confused and have the following question:

I have two .shp files from -

1. https://github.com/HindustanTimesLabs/shapefiles/blob/master/city/delhi/ward/delhi_ward.zip
2. https://github.com/datameet/Municipal_Spatial_Data/blob/master/Delhi/Delhi_Wards-SHP.zip

The second file has a CRS WGS84. The first one does not have any CRS attached to it. I tried the following code to assign CRS to the first file and getting intersection of areas between these two files. However, I am getting an error.

I am running the following code:

```
library(geojsonio)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

file_1 <- st_read("/my_path/delhi_ward/delhi_ward.shp")
file_2 <- st_read("/my_path/Delhi_Wards-SHP/Delhi_Wards.shp")

st_crs(file_1)
st_crs(file_2)
st_crs(file_2) <- 4326

sf_use_s2(FALSE)

intersection_area_new <- st_intersection(file_1, file_2) %>% 
  mutate(intersect_area = st_area(.), weight = round(intersect_area/file_2,3))
```

Error:

```
Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, x, y) : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at 77.26060286670301 28.676905354096.
```

My R version is:

```
platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20      
arch           aarch64                     
os             darwin20                    
system         aarch64, darwin20           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          2.1                         
year           2022                        
month          06                          
day            23                          
svn rev        82513                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shapefiles aren't compliant with the Simple Features standard, and GEOS is telling you there's a self-intersection, ie a polygon that crosses itself.

The self-intersection location stated leads me to polygon 39, and I can plot it and the intersection point:

```
> plot(file_1$geometry[39])
> points(77.26060286670301, 28.676905354096,pch="O",col="red")
```

[image]

You might not be able to see but there's a little triangle here where the polygon loops back and intersects itself. Polygons mustn't do that. Zoomed in, it does this:

[image]

This data is pretty broken. You can test for validity using `st_is_valid`, and 21 regions fail out of 272. Also, the boundaries of neighbouring polygons within `file_1` don't match up properly either:

[image]

But anyway, one way to fix the self-intersection geometry error is to run them through `st_make_valid` - read the docs to make sure it doesn't do anything destructive or detrimental to the analysis you are trying to do. Passing through that function lets the `st_intersection` operation work and the rest of your pipeline should then run (with some warnings, but also revealing your next error, most likely...)

```
> f1_v = st_make_valid(file_1)
> f2_v = st_make_valid(file_2)
> intersection_area_new <- st_intersection(f1_v, f2_v)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they
are planar
Warning message:
attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this can work for now. Thanks a lot! :)